# Using Pycaret for Random Forest Classifcation (Employee churn) in Power BI

Tags: python, machine-learning, powerbi, random-forest, pycaret

I'm trying to integrate my machine learning model (Random Forest) I did in Jupyter Notebook inside power BI. Using gridsearch , and after testing multiple algorithms, it turned out that the Random Forest was the most performant one for my dataset.

So I saved my model as a PKL file (rf_ins.PKL) and then I imported the model inside power BI using the Python visual. I used the following code:

```
from pycaret.regression import *
rf = load_model('C:/Users/hp/Desktop/Sprint PBI/rf_ins')

# Use the trained model to make predictions
predictions = predict_model(rf, data=dataset)

# Get the predicted label and score columns from the predictions
predicted_label = predictions['prediction_label']
predicted_score = predictions['prediction_score']

# Check if any element in predicted_label is equal to 1
if any(predicted_label == 1):
    output_text = "The employee is likely to leave with a probability of {:.2f}".format(predicted_score)
else:
    print(predicted_label)
    output_text = "The employee is not likely to leave"

# Return the output text
output_text
```

I get this error:

[image]

Here's a screenshot of my data:

[image]

I'll be actually have filters (slicers) next to the visualisation , which would correspond to my features and by changing the values of the prediction , my dashboard should be as follows

I was wondering why it's not correctly working. Any help is appreciated!
[image]

Comment: A Python visual is supposed to draw the visual output, not return a string.

Comment: What should i visualize then? for my case i don't really need plots or anything just a text label @DavidBrowne-Microsoft

Comment: Most Python visuals use matplotlib, which can render text. https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/mathtext_asarray.html#sphx-glr-gallery-text-labels-and-annotations-mathtext-asarray-py